# Eclipse IDE Double Clicking Java File In Project Explorer Expands It

Tags: eclipse

This may seem very small thing but it annoys me much since I'm used to code in Eclipse. When I double click a java source file in Eclipse it shows classes inside the file (expanding contents of java file) as marked by red circle in the image below. I wanna disable this behavior, I have used Eclipse for a long time and it has never been like this.

Comment: Have you search on Google for a solution? Or did you look on the Eclipse site?

Comment: It might be helpful to update with what version of eclipse you're using

Comment: Are you sure this is Project Explorer rather than Package Explorer?

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue with Eclipse Oxygen.2. The `build.gradle` icon shows that you are using an outdated Eclipse version. [Upgrading](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F) might fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Prefences --> Content Assist and Enable/Disable the contents of Java file

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks,
Raghava

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Eclipse, and several people have reported it, e.g., [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=310618).
One workaround is to change the "open mode" in the General preferences to single click", which does not have this annoying behaviour.